# If a government dislikes the way its citizens are acting, would dropping bombs be an appropriate response?

Tags: warfare, government, weapon-mass-destruction

The government is upset with the way the citizens are responding to lack of care, jobs, etc. So is dropping bombs on their own country (in a way to stop the revolting and keep the citizens in line) appropriate, if the citizens are rioting and creating resistances against the existing government?

Comment: Appropriate? No. Usually done? Yes

Comment: Very reasonable. On top of that: If you drop enough bombs, some of those problems will get solved. The construction industry will boom, less jobs will be needed and more money per citizen can go into social care

Comment: @nzaman Usually done? Where do you live?

Comment: @Raditz_35: Planet Earth...

Comment: @Raditz_35 Please tell me that pun was intentional...

Comment: @Raditz_35 google Tienanmen Square...Ok, so it wasn't bombs, but that kind of action went on throughout history.

Comment: Appropriate in what sense?  Moral/ethical?  Pragmatic (effectiveness)?  Do you want to know about side effects?  E.g. will the military side with the government or the citizens?

Comment: @PaulTIKI Not even close. Yes, there were some occasions that came close, most recently Syria, but "usually", come on. That's such a simplistic view

Comment: Welcome to the site, Lovi. Are you asking this question as a geopolitical inquiry, or because you want to know if a certain group of people -- in this case, an unspecified form of governing body -- would take a specific action in response to a specific catalyst? The former question might be straying from the purpose of the Worldbuilding SE, while the latter might be straying into storybuilding.

Comment: @Brythan I was wondering if it was something a (tyrannical) government would do to it's own country. I can only assume it's morally wrong, because why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @LoviJones Could you describe the situation in that country in more detail? *usually* tyrannical governments have other, more effective and less destructive ways. Actual warfare is only used if the country is in open rebellion and there is an actual faction with their own army one can fight against. Whom do you want to bombard? Why? Who doesn't get bombed? I think you need to give some details ...

Comment: @Raditz_35  I'm referring to the whole of history.  Ghengiz Kahn destroyed entire cities for an insult.  Quelling rebellions is nothing new.  Saddam Hussein gassed entire Kurdish towns.  How many of his own people did Vlad Tepisc impale?  Brutal regimes often take to extreme measures to stop dissent.  A bomb or two is not a major stretch to consider.

Comment: @PaulTIKI It's not a major stretch. Horrible things have been done. But claiming it's "usually done" this way is as wrong as a statement can be. I'm curious what the purpose of your comment is. Do you think I'm unaware of let's say the Holocaust?

Comment: @Raditz_35 Heavens no!  I meant no offense.  I'm just a little cynical about how many brutal regimes humanity has had throughout history.  They vastly outnumber the benign.  I claim "usually done" in light of some recent events like Syria and Northern Iraq, and that there are plenty of other places throughout the world who would do it if they thought they could get away with it.  North Korea for one...

Comment: Asking "Is action x an appropriate response for event y?" is not about building a world.

Comment: @Raditz_35: Usual in the sense that every country has _at least_ one such incident in its history. Whether it's Ivan the Terrible or Colonel Dyer (later General), _every_ regime has done something like this at some time in its history.

Comment: @PaulTIKI (also nzaman but I can only ping one, go figure): I'm not easily offended ;). Fine, but the question is specifically about the use of bombs. I think one needs to be precise here since the OP was that specific. I find the approach very unusual and I feel like saying "that's what most people do, look at France right now, they have recently used water throwsers against protesters" is, well, misleading

Comment: It is "usually done" when the citizens actually put the political system in danger. Citizens don't "usually" do that, though.

Comment: @Raditz_35 ahhh...precision.  Sorry for being a bit vague today.  I left my tape measure and calipers are at home, I just have to eyeball it ;) Bombs are a bit indiscriminate to be a normal tool of the brutal regime, but can still be used as a tool for the villain in a hurry.  The purpose of which is to engender fear in the populace at large so they will behave or be reduced to rubble  No need to put your Jackbooted thugs at risk.  I have also noted that this usually happens in times of upheaval, like right after a dictator takes power, or after a period of massive abuse

Comment: I would watch the final episode (or two episodes) of Deep Space 9 to show an example of why this is not a good idea.  If you have a rebellion that's saying the government is terrible, and in order to quash it, you drop bombs on them, you risk killing innocents...  Sure... the leader of the rebellion was asking Joe Schmo to kill his fellow countrymen and betray his homeland... but his fellow countrymen and homeland just killed his wife and kids...  Suddenly Rebel Leader isn't looking crazy all of a sudden.

Comment: I'm surprised anyone's disputing the point that there's a history of states violently repressing populations. As for bombing, specifically: look at civil wars in the age of air power.

Comment: I'm asking to re-open on the theory that this question is really saying "What mindset could a government have to make this sound like a good idea?"

Comment: @akaioi If you think that's it, then you should ideally (1) get buy-in from the OP on that interpretation of the question, and (2) either propose (make, since you're above 3,000) such an edit, or (better) encourage the OP to edit the question in such a way. Mind that such an edit shouldn't invalidate any existing answers (I haven't looked closely enough to tell if that'd be the case here).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I don't want to edit myself, because I'm not quite sure that's what he wants; hoping OP notices the comments and takes decisive action!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR -- Yes, yep, and heck yeah.  Our own history is rife with it**

Well ... where I grew up the idea was that the government exists at the people's sufferance, and it would be beyond gauche to drop bombs on citizens.  So...

You're worldbuilding, right?  You need to find an ethos which makes the government decide that bombing their own populace is (a) conceivable, (b) appropriate, and (c) the best option.

Some thoughts:

- Maybe the government identifies as a different people than the citizenry.  Think Gothic overlords in Roman lands.  If those cats had had airstrike capability they would have used it liberally on the peons, whom they didn't much like anyway.
- Could be the aristocracy has some kind of religious mandate, and it is impious to oppose them [1].  Those heretics down in the streets deserve what they get for opposing the Chosen One's government!
- Might be that the government is led by some kind of "vanguard party" which is defending some kind of philosophy or ideology.  If other parties are illegal, street demonstrations are nearly obscene!  [2]
- Could be as free, nice, and rational of a government as you want.  But the nation is in crisis.  Invasions in the provinces or whatnot.  All effort must be spent making weapons to repel the foe.  Rationing is strict because there's barely any food.  We **have** to get people back to work if there's any chance of winning the war!

All the above have analogues from our own world.  If you want to get all fictiony on us, hmm...

- The birthrate is skyrocketing.  There are too many people.  Some must be slain or we will all starve!
- For sinister reasons, we want to invade Country X.  What a shame an airplane painted in their hated colors dropped bombs on our beloved populace!  But hey, the war party is suddenly so much more popular...

And so on.  Good luck quelling the Revolution!

[1]  Side-note.  In the Byzantine Empire, the Emperor was the Viceregent of Christ.  Meaning that it was God's will that he be in charge.  Hence attempted usurpation was criminal and blasphemous, and punished hideously.  However, **successful** usurpation just showed God's will in action, yo.

[2]  Nothing from this bullet point is stolen from real history.  Honest.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, governments have less heavy-handed methods to deal with riots, i.e. riot police. Bombs destroy the riches of the state - so is, government taxes are literally blown up - and just because of this is not a good idea, moral aside. Bombs are used normally when people is starting to riot very violently, and they are armed - and they may win. In these cases, it's called a revolution or a civil war, depending on how much support the government is able to muster.

Comment: Also bear in mind that bombs _per se_ are a comparatively recent invention. Until the internal combustion/diesel engine was invented, there was simply no way to get explosive ordnance/artillery to a riot fast enough. It's only since the start of the last century that we had aircraft and tanks. Before that, the options were hand held mortars (only useful against large,stationary targets), and grenades. The problem with the latter was that it was far too easy to cause massive carnage in your own ranks if just one grenadier were captured or mutinied in the face of having to attack civilians.